# How can I reduce sheen with touched-up wall paint?

Tags: painting, repainting

[image: Stairway touch-up.]

I touched up some paint spots on my stairway wall. When looking straight at the touch-ups, it looks blended in well with no obvious patch work. However, when looking at the paint at certain angles, it appears shiny/glossy as seen in the picture. How can I fix this issue? Thanks

Comment: Same can of paint as the original? Stirred well?

Comment: Took a small part of the wall and brought it to Home Depot. They color matched it. Only see the glossy finish at certain angles. Straight on it looks perfect.

Comment: Same brand? Same sheen? (See where this is going?)

Comment: I do. It was a different brand. Sherwin Williams initially, Behr second time around. Any way to lessen the gloss?

Comment: I have the same problem here. There's no reliable way of deglossing chemically. You could end up with a worse situation. You could try scuffing the repair with a rag or steel wool. Do a small area lightly and examine it. Work slowly and carefully.

Comment: I read online elsewhere to try Krud Kutter Deglosser. Ever heard of that?

Comment: I've heard of deglossers in general. The point is that you may end up with a flat spot in your wall rather than a shiny spot, or it may affect color, or it may do much worse. It's not a reliable approach.

Comment: Ahh I see. What about Magic Erasers? Would those work?

Comment: You could try a matte clear coat, sold in roll/brush on cans as well as spray cans.  Googling "matte clear coat" (for me) brings up results for Home Depot and Amazon.  A light spray might be all you need.

Comment: You need to repaint with the proper sheen.  If you used matte, try flat.  If flat is still too shiny, use ceiling paint, which is just about the flattest you can get.  If that doesn't do you, you'll just need to do the entire wall.

Answer (score 2):

My 2 cents...

I had the same issue and the painter told me the best course of action was to paint that one entire wall.

His reasoning was he could get the color very close, but never perfect and there was a good chance my eye would see the touch up.  Doing the entire wall fakes your eye into seeing the color as a whole.  In my house, my eye can't tell the difference so it was worth the money.

Caveat:  Obviously you can't paint one side flat the other gloss, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I got this tip from a painter for another situation but it really worked.  I touched up some nail holes (after spackling them) with the same paint (same gallon) as originally used (12 years ago!!).  The areas where touched  up were very shiny. Paint had only been on a couple of hours. I used Windex (the painter stressed the brand) and rubbed gently. Success!!!!