# Paint flashing after touch up

Tags: painting, flashing, diy-vs-pro

We recently had our dining room decorated by professionals (about 3 weeks ago).

This week we had to do some touch-ups ourselves after a stain got on our wall. We used a roller however unfortunately while it looks fine head on there is some pretty unsightly flashing when looking at a side angle (the room picks up quite a lot of natural light).

What options do we have here to get this fixed - can I do anything on the touch up area or will I have to paint the whole wall again (if painting a whole section, would hope to get away with just the section above the fireplace)?

The room was painted using a Valspar classic paint match. We did touch-ups with paint at the end of the pot so would have to get another pot of paint if we need to do a section.

Thanks for your help in advance.

[image: flashing]

Comment: Did you stir the paint thoroughly? Flatting compound will often settle and if not mixed properly, will affect sheen.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate A very good point. I use flattening agent in my *very, very glossy* marine paints, and it will separate **right in the paint pot** when brushing. I've had to redo work because of this.

Comment: How many coats, and did you let this fully dry/seal before topcoat?  What is the sheen of the paint?

Comment: Thanks for your help all - will try and do another coat with a bit of water added (and will ensure properly mixed).

Comment: Or this? [How can I reduce sheen with touched-up wall paint?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/129356/how-can-i-reduce-sheen-with-touched-up-wall-paint)

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if the paint was not mixed well before you tried the touch up.

Try adding just a bit of water to the paint to thin it. Mix it very well. Paint with a brush and light strokes.

If still not to your liking, the only choice is to paint the entire wall from one intersection to the other.  A quart of new paint should do it.

Comment: Yes, failure to mix sufficiently will cause this.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, if you have lights from several sources, especially parallel to the wall, then you just have to paint the whole wall.

Another reason for this is, if the paint is not an original mix, then it will never be an exact match to the original.